# How can I find the callers of a method?

Tags: java, eclipse

Usually to find the callers of a method in Eclipse I use ctrl-alt-h on the method. If nothing comes up, it is a callback from some other library. I'm pretty certain this method is not a callback and I'm pretty certain it's being called from somewhere. How can I find out if nothing shows up with a ctrl-alt-h?

Answer (score 4):

You can put the cursor on the method name and press `Ctrl-Shift-G` (default key combination).

This will open a search in the project to look for references to your method.

**Edit**

On frameworks using declarative markup (Spring, Android, etc.) you might actually need to use a more manual approach: the file search.

- Copy or highlight your method name
- Press `Ctrl-H` (default binding) and select `File search` (you can assign a custom key binding for that but no custom is provided)
- Fill the `containing text` with your method name if not automatically filled
- Optionally, select "case sensitive", or your file pattern if any
- Then select your scope (the project should be a good place to start)

Comment: The things I don't know about Eclipse never cease to amaze me!

Comment: @Compass it's full of features and gadgets! I always learn something new too :)

Comment: You can also right-click on the method name and pick "References -> Workspace" from the popup menu.  Ctrl-Shift-G is a shortcut for that.

Comment: Good thing to know but no luck for me =(

Comment: @Barodapride just saw the update in your question. Will update my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Other tactics include:

- If the method is implementing a interface, ask Eclipse for the callers of the interface method. Sometimes Eclipse will identify more callers through the interface method, particularly when callers don't know they're using a particular implementation.
- Similarly, if the method is overriding a base class method, ask Eclipse for the callers of that.
- Put a breakpoint in the method, and look at the call stack in the debugger.
- If it's possible that the Java method might be called by native code through JNI, use text search for the Java method name in the native code.
- If available, ask the authors of the method.

Comment: It is implementing an interface but when I ctrl-alt-h the interface declaration it points me back to the interface declaration. Ctrl-Shift-G shows nothing.

Comment: My last resort would be to use a breakpoint because I'm just trying to copy some code from another codebase. I really don't want to have to rebuild the code but maybe that's the only option.

Comment: I don't think they used any native code but I'm not super familiar the codebase. Maybe I can manually track it down but if Eclipse isn't finding anything I don't know how I would.

Comment: It may be necessary to build the code for Eclipse to identify the callers.

Comment: I was able to find it. They are doing some weird stuff where they get the class and get the method programmatically. Then they eventually call the method with a method.invoke(args...). I'll have to spend some more time with the code to see why they do it like that.